# Load dyanmic resource drawable using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I want to load multiple drawable-resources in RecyclerView and i am using Picasso in RecyclerView.ViewHolder for this task.

> Picasso.with(context)
>                       .load(imageList.get(position))
>                       .into(imageView);

Picasso loads the drawable-resources which are in drawable folder but it doesn't load resources from other drawable.

For example if i put the drawables in all drawable folders(mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi etc) except "drawable" folder, It doesn't work.

So is there something I am  missing? is it possible to dynamic reference to the drawables using Picasso?

Comment: You can also use the 'glide' for loading the images from the internet or sd card

Comment: I have to use Picasso for other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picasso should load mipmaps. Try forcing just one to show, like

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(imageView);
```

and see if is loading. If it is, there is something with your id's from array.

Comment: Thanks. I've realized that  the images that were not loading are Drawable-selectors. So can i use Drawable-selectors with Picasso?